# Sonar-Runner 2.4 can't find code coverage reports

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sonar-runner, vstest

I'm running SonarQube 5.2 with SonarRunner v2.4 (MSBuild) and am having issues getting SonarRunner to pick up the code coverage reports. I have VS Test which drops the TestResults folder within the source directory. The TRX file is within the TestResults folder. Is there a default directory that Sonar-Runner scans to search for the TRX/code coverage reports? The build succeeds but there are no unit test coverage results in SonarQube for the app.

**TRX:** F:\Builds\50\IT\ABCDemo.Nightly\src\TestResults\ *.TRX

**Source:**
F:\Builds\50\IT\ABCDemo.Nightly\src

Process:

- SonarRunner begin //with key,name,version  filled in
- MSBuild executes
- VS Test executes and drops TestResults folder within src directory.
- SonarRunner end

Issue:

MSBuild SonarQube Runner Post-processor 1.0.2.0

09:22:57.327  Fetching code coverage report information from TFS...

09:23:17.723  **No code coverage reports were found for the current build.**

---

**EDIT: I've included the .TRX and .coveragexml files using /d: but I still get the issue saying no code coverage reports were found.**

I can see in the logs that it does:

09:51:59.875 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report f:\Builds\50\IT\ABCDemo.Nightly\src\VisualStudio.coveragexml

09:53:07.737 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio Test Results file f:\Builds\50\IT\ABCDemo.Nightly\src\TestResults\tfsbuildagent_QL1CIBUILD3 2015-12-03 09_51_33.trx

These occur near the end of sonar analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by:

Included the paths to the files for trx and coveragexmls within the arguments for sonar-runner.

> MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin
>   /k:projectkey    /n:projectname  /v:projectversion
>   /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="path\to\ *.trx"
>   /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths="path\to\VisualStudio.coveragexml"

Moved the /'s around for better visual.